# How to create mysql db for account balace, add and subtract amounts

Tags: mysql

I have project like online service, i have made some part and stopped. If user use service it must take some amount (e.g. 5$ per service). I don't know how to build MySQL tables. I have made 2 tables 1st for rest amount 2nd for add and subtract amounts. May be this is wrong way, what is the best practice?
action_table

```
id | userId | reason         | amount
1  |      4 | for service 3  |     -5
2  |      2 | refill account |    100
3  |     13 | for service 3  |     -5
```

balance_table

```
1  |      4 |  23
2  |      2 | 125
3  |     13 |   0
```

After using service query adds one row to `action_table` and updates `balance_table`

Comment: This question is very broad, as database design can vary depending on application requirements. Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I have no idea, am i on the right way or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, if I was making an account database, I would have one table for an account and one for transactions, like this:

```
Accounts:
| id | user | name | balance |

Transactions:
| id | account_id | description | amount | is_withdrawal |
```

The reason I came up with this is because it helps to think of database tables like real world objects sometimes, and in this case you have a Transaction and an Account.

Then, you can use a `TRIGGER` to update the account table anytime you add a transaction.